# What is the purpose of ubuntu-vg partiton?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

So, I'm new to partitioning and recently I installed ubuntu 13.10. I followed several online tutorials on how to create disk partitions effectively and all of them said that after ubuntu is done installing, I should have three partitions - home, swap and root. I installed GParted and saw that I only have two partitions - boot and ubuntu-vg, which is a part of an extended partition. My question is is ubuntu-vg a replacement for mentioned partitions? If I will want to, say, dual boot ubuntu with windows in sooner future, is it dangerous to resize it or mess with it in any other way? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 3):

'vg' is a Volume Group, used in Logical Volume Management https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm  and not needed for simple installations. However, there's nothing wrong with it, per se, and should you go dual-boot later, it will be no more problematic than standard partitioning.

Comment: Ok, so the files that would usually be stored in root/home/swap are  all in the -vg partition?

Comment: Yes, that's what's going on.